# Memory Deallocation Simulation Issue

Tags: c, memory-management, simulation

I am simulating a memory block with a static array of structs that take the form of:

```
typedef struct memBlock
{
  unsigned int isAllocated = 0;
  unsigned int processID = 0;
}memBlock;
```

I have already got a `malloc()`-like function that will simulates malloc by taking in the requested memory size from a process and marking part of the array as occupied by setting the isAllocated equal to 1, and changing the PID to the process ID of the requesting process.

So now I want to write a function like `free` that will deallocate "memory" from this array by setting isAllocated to 0 and PID to 0, but how should I accomplish this? I know conceptually that I need to start at index 0 of this array and maybe check for the first index where isAllocated = 1 and a nonzero PID right? 
I already have this implemented so far:

```
void* custom_free(void* ptr, unsigned int size)
{
    unsigned int blockIndex = 0, sizeCount = 0, startIndex = 0;
    if(ptr){ free(ptr); }
}
```

Edit: Earlier in my code I have a malloc call for the memBlock structure like this:

`memBlock *block = (memBlock *)malloc(BLOCK_SIZE);`

where `BLOCK_SIZE` is a preprocessor defined constant

Comment: @WhiZTiM The removal of the C++ tag might have been premature, as inline initialization of structure members like shown in the `memBlock` structure is not possible in C, but it is in C++.

Comment: This is not C, but C++. You should use C++ `new`/`delete` operators. And remove the C tag.

Comment: Maybe you did not understand my comment. So to repeat: **this is not C code, but C++** C and C++ are different languages and you are required to use the correct tag.

Comment: Yes, I removed the C++ tag earlier. It is not C++.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, noted. I wouldn't be in a hurry next time. :: Nonetheless, I just had a laugh checking the revision history of this post... Tag Wars :-)

Answer (score 1):

A common way to store information about allocated memory blocks by an allocator is to store the information structure in the memory block it allocates.

So instead of allocating `size` bytes, you allocate `size + sizeof(memBlock)` bytes, and use the pointer as a pointer to a `memBlock` structure and fill in the information you need. Then return a pointer to the memory after the `memBlock` structure (i.e. something like `&((memBlock *) ptr)[1]`).

When freeing you subtract the size of a `memBlock` structure to get the original pointer, which points to the `memBlock` structure.

This of course makes a member such as `isAllocated` pretty much useless. If you have your own blocks, and only allocate in multiples of those blocks, you need to store information about which blocks was allocated, and the number of blocks as well.

Comment: This makes more sense, but why specifically is `isAllocated`now useless? How else can I differentiate between an occupied and empty block besides using `isAllocated`?